# Change store in top.links magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I've an ecommerce with five stores, I would like to set the top.links (my account, checkout, login, logout etc.) to store default.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I used this for mine, hopefully it helps you

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/26245/viewthread/196486/#t245022

Comment: P.S  I am using Magento CE 1.7.0.2